# Git push to server remote issues

Tags: git, deployment

I am out of ideas and need some please.

I am trying to push changes form my local computer to the remote server where the project is used.

I am sort of using this guide: http://ryanflorence.com/deploying-websites-with-a-tiny-git-hook/

I add the remote on my local machine like so

`$git remote add stage ssh://user@domain.com/var/www/domain.com/public_htm`l

This /var/www/domain.com/public_html  is the path the the repo

Then when I do

```
$git push stage stage
```

all seems to work but the changes do not seem to appear on the website.

So checking the remote (stage) #git status I can see

```
$ On branch stage
$ Changes to be committed:
$   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
$
$   modified:   sites/all/modules/custom/bf/bf.forms.inc
$
```

So doing a #git reset --hard on remote (stage) brings in the changes.

I then add a post-receive hook to automate this process
My post-receive file contains

```
#!/bin/sh
cd ..
GIT_DIR='.git'
umask 002 && git reset --hard
```

But now when I do 
$git push stage stage  i get this result

> Counting objects: 24, done. Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
>   Compressing objects: 100% (16/16), done. Writing objects: 100%
>   (16/16), 1.56 KiB, done. Total 16 (delta 10), reused 0 (delta 0)
>   remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/stage
>   remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare
>   repository remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index
>   and work tree inconsistent remote: error: with what you pushed, and
>   will require 'git reset --hard' to match remote: error: the work tree
>   to HEAD. remote: error:  remote: error: You can set
>   'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to remote: error:
>   'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
>   remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended
>   unless you remote: error: arranged to update its work tree to match
>   what you pushed in some remote: error: other way. remote: error: 
>   remote: error: To squelch this message and still keep the default
>   behaviour, set remote: error: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch'
>   configuration variable to 'refuse'. To
>   ssh://user@domain.com/var/www/domain.com/public_html  ! [remote
>   rejected] stage -> stage (branch is currently checked out) error:
>   failed to push some refs to
>   'ssh://user@domain.com/var/www/domain.com/public_html'

How do I rectify this? I mean based on the message this is not a recommend workflow is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message tells you pretty clearly what you need to do: Log onto your server and run `git config receive.denyCurrentBranch ignore`.

Typically, git is set up so that you can `git pull` from any repository, bare or not bare, but `git push` only happens to a bare repository. (A 'bare' repository is one that doesn't have a working directory; the contents of the folder are the contents of the `.git` directory.) This makes sense; if you had checked out a branch and I pushed a new version of the same branch to your machine, your working directory would suddenly be out of date and your next commit would probably revert a lot of the things I just pushed. That's bad.

In this setup, the working directory is the directory which your web server reads and which nobody commits, you actually want git to update the working directory immediately, and you have a post-update hook that does "update its work tree to match what you pushed in some other way". You can turn off the error message and go about your business.

In case you were curious, `git reset --hard` will clear out your local changes and ensure your working directory is the same as HEAD. Like with most things in git, there are multiple ways to do the same thing, and you could easily have written `git checkout HEAD .`. One recommendation, though: Add a `git clean -df` as well. `git checkout` and `git reset` typically do not delete files that you haven't added to git, so if you want a deleted file to disappear from your server you'll need to specifically instruct git to do so.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Excellent no more errors when I push. But still no working for me. SO I guess the issue is in post-receive? I added git clean -df as suggested like so umask 002 && git reset --hard && git clean -df

Comment: Are you sure your post-receive file runs? You renamed it from .sample and added execute permissions? My next diagnostic step would be to `touch /tmp/githooktest` in the line before `cd`.

Comment: Actually I just notice there is an when I do a push error: cannot run hooks/post-receive: No such file or directory ANy ideas

Comment: I'd say to check the permissions. It seems like git is fine with the file there, or without the file there, but it may not like it if the file is there but without permissions. [This link](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/error-cannot-run-hooks-pre-receive-No-such-file-or-directory-td6223295.html) also reminds you to ensure that the shebang is there and that there's nothing wrong with the interpreter path. Can you cd into that directory and run `./post-receive`?